# How to specify multiple file types for Azure Function Blob Trigger input binding?

Tags: json, azure-functions, azure-storage, inputbinding

I'm looking to only allow the upload of specific filetypes to Azure Storage to trigger an Azure Function.

**Current `function.json` file:**

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [{
        "name": "myblob",
        "type": "blobTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "path": "{name}.json",
        "connection": "storage-dev"
    }]
}
```

**Would I just add another `path` value like this...**

```
"path": "{name}.json",
"path": "{name}.csv"
```

**...or an array of values like this...**

```
"path": [
    "{name}.csv",
    "{name}.json"
]
```

Can't seem to find an example in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#filter-on-blob-name).

**EDIT:**
Thank you @BowmanZhu! Your guidance was awesome.

- Changed trigger to `EventGrid`
- Actually was able to create a single `Advanced Filter` rather than create multiple Subscriptions:
  [image]

Comment: Blob trigger is no way to do this, what you are searching for is event grid trigger.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=csharp#create-a-subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a blobtrigger to monitor two or more paths at the same time.

I can tell you simply, it's impossible. This is why you can't find the relevant documentation, because there is no such thing. If you must use blobtrigger at the same time according to your requirements, you can only use multiple blobtrigger.

But you have another option: eventgridtrigger:

[image]

You just need to create multiple event grid, and let them point to the same endpoint function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not looking to monitor multiple *paths*, but rather only trigger on specific *file types*. Do you know how this is accomplished using Blob trigger?

Comment: @ericOnline I know your requirement is specific types. I'm afraid blobtrigger can't realize your idea. Have you see my screenshot? Just create a event grid end with a suffix and create another event grid end with another suffix.

Comment: I don't have EventGrid setup. That means I'd have to deploy entire EventGrid RG and support resources, etc. Certainly there is a way to `"path": "{name}.{json, csv}"` or the like, isn't there?

Comment: I'm following your advice @BowmanZhu. Setting up an `Event` for the storage account wasn't that big of a deal. Refactoring the python code to accommodate `EventGrid` trigger is taking a bit more work, but I think I can get it. Then updating `function.json`.