# How to trigger Azure Function from any file uploaded to Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure-functions, inputbinding

Single Azure Function. I want it to trigger from **all files** uploaded to an Azure Storage account. The Storage Account has multiple top-level containers, so I can't specify one container, must be the entire account.

How is the `function.json` file handled?

This doesn't seem to be triggering the Function:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [{
        "name": "myblob",
        "type": "blobTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "path": "{name}.json",
        "connection": "storage-dev"
    }]
}
```

Does the path need a leading `/`? (`"path": "/{name}.json"`)

Comment: No you don't need leading slash `/`. You mentioned `"connection": "storage-dev"` in app settings?

Comment: Yes. `"storage-dev" : "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname/uid)"` (Using KeyVault reference)

Comment: You can first test with one container and giving the container proper access

Comment: you can subscribe to all BlobCreated events in a specific storage account ,i can show you how to do that if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to use an `EventGrid` trigger rather than `BlobTrigger`. Thank you to @BowmanZhu over [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63947277/10426490) for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to specify all containers as the trigger path in a blob trigger function. The solution I can think of is to create multiple functions and specify different containers respectively, so that you can achieve your expectations.